# Can I install Python 3.10.6 on D drive?

Tags: python

Is there any problem if I install Python 3.10.6 on my D drive? Because I am not OK to install on C drive.

Comment: You can have python almost everywhere, while there is an OS to execute it. So, your answer is YES.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can, but make sure you add the path variable properly. I believe the python installer asks you if you want to add it to PATH, if not then add the install location of python to your path variables. [Add to PATH](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-add-edit-a-path-variable-in-windows)